# Collect Undefined Parameters PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to be able to accept many paramas that I don't want to define. I generated a function which worked fine in testing to display "Hello World", but of course in practice doesn't work as intended. I'm trying to use it with a `Microsoft Word COM Object` and getting the following error:

```
Exception setting "Open": Cannot convert the "TRUE" value of type "string" to type "Object".
```

Here is the param grabbing section of my code for grabbing all "extra" params.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    $UndefinedArgs
)


IF ($UndefinedArgs) {
 $UndefinedArgs | ForEach-Object {
  IF ($_ -like '-*') {
   $ObjName = $_ -replace '^-'
  } ELSE {
   Set-Variable -Name "$ObjName" -Value "$_"
   $UndefinedArgsArr = @()
   $UndefinedArgsArr + @([pscustomobject]@{VarName="$ObjName";VarVal="$_"})
  }
 }
}
$UndefinedArgsArr
Write-Host $READONLY
```

The issue somehow is that I can't pass `$FALSE` because if I code `$READONLY = $FALSE` my code works, but if I pass `-READONLY $FALSE` with or without `$` I get the above error. I left out my statement that is giving me trouble as I think the above function needs to be adjusted, not that statement, but I can add it if needed.

Comment: `I left out my statement that is giving me trouble as I think the above function needs to be adjusted, not that statement, but I can add it if needed.` Please show that too. A string is an object (`"" -is [object]`), so that error is a bit confusing. But you might be right about the quotes in the value portion, as `"$_"` will implicitly convert `$_` to a string. Leaving out quotes will preserve the type.

Comment: This is a bad design as it is possible to easily inject any variable, e.g. `-ObjName`. You should use predefined parametersets instead.

Comment: @iRon thanks for your two cents but thats not the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining params like so, I was able to surpass the error.

```
IF (!$READONLY){$READONLY = $TRUE}ELSE{$READONLY = [bool]$READONLY}
```

The issue being I had to set the variable to `[bool]`. I also removed the quotes around `$_`.